# Is there some agreement about memory allocation?

Tags: c++

```
class http_client {
public:
    void init(const char url*);
    void download();
}

int main() {
    http_client c1;
    {
        char url[] = "www.example.com"; // url allocated on stack
        c1.init(url);
    }   // <<<<< url is destroyed
    c1.connect();
    // do something else
}
```

In the above example there are two possibilites:

1. http_client.init() alloactes memory for url, copies it and stores somewhere for future use
2. http_client.init() stores only a pointer to url

In the variant №2 the c1.connect() will fail because url is destroyed before conenct();

In general both variants are possible. Sometimes it is desired to avoid extra copying of strings, arrays or other containers, especially when there is a bunch of abstraction layers, each storing a copy of a string.

The only way to distinguish from these two variants is to look into documentation or inside the init() method, to see does it store string content or just a pointer.

Is there some recommendation, or agreement, or naming convention of methods that make a deep copy of arguments and methods that copy only a pinter/reference ?

Comment: With modern C++, if the parameter is a pointer, it is just available for the duration of the routine.  If the routine wants to maintain a copy for longer than the duration of the routine, it should make its own copy.  Alternatively, there is a way to express an intentional transfer of ownership by a parameter like `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, or in this case even simpler `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, intentional transfer of ownership, that is!
But how to express, that method doesn't want to get ownership and caller have to extend the lifetime of a method argument for the lifetime of an object?

Comment: Sounds like you want `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr`.  Those come with some baggage, though:  they make the object effectively a global (which is okay if the object is immutable, because it is `const`), some extra burden on the caller of the API, the control block, possibly concerns for threading (...but isn't that the perennial problem with threading in general anyway?).

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` takes ownership, `std::shared_ptr` stores a copy of the pointer, `T*` borrows a pointer to a single object for the duration of the function. For arrays you have `std::array`, `std::vector` or, if you must, `std::span`. Figure out what those say about ownership.

Comment: Sometimes there is also the possibility to move objects into the class.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some recommendation

Yes. Storing the data inside the class is recommended default choice. This is because it is safer and less reliant on documentation.

However, it's typically preferred to initialise using a constructor and not a normal member function.

> or naming convention of methods

There are loose naming conventions for *types*. Types named like "view" or "ptr" or "ref" often refer to objects stored elsewhere. Since types that don't have reference semantics are the default choice, they don't need a naming hint.

Furthermore, constructors that accept pointers parameters are more often considered to potentially retain the reference for later use, while such consideration isn't typical when the parameter is a reference. That's not necessarily safe assumption when name is like "ref" etc though. Consider `std::reference_wrapper` as such exception.